# How to loop through each discrete instance of a class within another instance of a different class and call a specific method

Tags: c#, class, reflection

I have a class that uses a variety of methods and other classes as its members.  In one of these methods, it does something like this:

```
MyObject.member1.doStuff();
MyObject.member2.doStuff();
MyObject.member3.doStuff();
MyObject.member4.doStuff();
```

etc.

I would like to do something like this instead:

```
foreach Member in MyObject
{
    foreach Method in Member
        {
            if (Method.Name == "doStuff")
                { Method.Invoke() }
        }
}
```

Each member is of a different class type, the only thing they have in common is they will all have a void method called doStuff().  I cannot combine all methods into one giant doStuff() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the members you are talking about are properties, you can do the following very ugly code:

```
foreach (var property in MyObject.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(MyObject, null)))
{
    property.GetType().GetMethod("doStuff").Invoke(property, null);
}
```

But as has been mentioned, it seems like a problem with your architecture.

Comment: I was hoping to do it like this because I'm adding more properties to this class as I develop it, and didn't want to have to keep updating a giant doStuff() method with all the separate methods.  Each property's value is randomly generated, but each class type has its own method for random generation.  This allows the user to randomly generate each property of the item one at a time, or all at once using one method.

Answer (score 3):

you have to use interface here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.doStuff();
}

interface IMember
{
    void doStuff();
}

class Member1 : IMember
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Member1");
    }
}

class Member2 : IMember
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Member2");
    }
}

class Member3 : IMember
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Member3");
    }
}

class Member4 : IMember
{
    public void doStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Member4");
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public Member1 member1 = new Member1();
    public Member2 member2 = new Member2();
    public Member3 member3 = new Member3();
    public Member4 member4 = new Member4();

    public void doStuff()
    {
        IMember[] members = { member1, member2, member3, member4 };
        foreach (IMember member in members)
            member.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using an interface. Also provides compile time type safety.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use reflection for method calls on properties like that it means your code is most likely ill-designed.

If you know the methods already you can just put them into an `Action` array though:

```
Action [] methods= { MyObject.member1.doStuff, MyObject.member2.doStuff, 
                     MyObject.member3.doStuff, MyObject.member4.doStuff};

foreach(var method in methods)
    method();
```